# How to fire/show popover on span tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a span tag as below and need some suggestions to show a popover. With the following code snippet, the popover is not showing for enter key / space bar, whereas it is working fine for mouse click. Any suggestions to popover using enter key for the span tag would be helpful and appreciated.

```
<span role="button" aria-pressed="false" tabindex="0" id="btnPopover" class="btn btn-primary" title="popover button" data-content="This is span popover" data-trigger="click" data-toggle="popover">Span Popover</span>

$(function() {
        $(document).popover({
            selector: '[data-toggle=popover]',
            trigger: 'click',
            container: 'body'
        }); 

        $('#btnPopover').keydown(function(){
            $(document).popover({
                selector: '[data-toggle=popover]',
                trigger: 'click',
                container: 'body'
            });             
        }); 

});
```

I tried with the options mentioned in the above code.

When I use mouse click, the popover displayed as expected, but it is not working for enter key or space bar.

When I tried various options, it was always working for mouse clicks, but not for space bar / enter key.

Comment: updated the html as below...  <span id="Id1_fieldHelpers" role="button">
 <span role="button" id="Id1_fieldHelperBalloon" class="tooltip-balloon" data-placement="right" data-toggle="popover" data-html="true" data-trigger="click"
  data-content="Enter the value for Id1." tabindex="0" data-original-title="" title="">  
  <i class="fa fa-2 balloon"></i>
 </span>
</span>

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover(); 
  
  $('#Id1_fieldHelpers').keydown(function(){
   $('#Id1_fieldHelpers').popover();
  });  
  
  $('#Id1_fieldHelperBalloon').keypress(function(){
   $('#Id1_fieldHelperBalloon').popover();
  });

Comment: used the above updated span tags and javascript as well to try out. Still no luck on this. Not able to show popover on span tag when enter key / space bar pressed. Any thoughts would be helpful here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if i use data-trigger='focus', then i am able to show / fire a popover for span tag while using tab to focus that popover element (span tag). Thanks!